# Inverse of equation $c = A^e \pmod{n}$

Tags: calculus

I have a modular equation: $c = A^e \pmod{n}$

If I know $e,n,c$, how can I find $A$?

For example $e=17, n=3233, c= 2790$, how can I get to $A = 65$?

Comment: You probably mean "modular", and this is an equation, not the "inverse of an equation".

Comment: PLease read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: That's a [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), and it's not easy to find.

Comment: This is **no** discrete loagrithm problem, you have to find modular  $e$'th roots.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of finding modular $e$'th roots. In your case this is relative easy, because you have $\gcd(e, \varphi(n))=1$. The solution can be calculated as follows. With $m=\varphi(n)=3120$ compute the modular inverse of $e$ modulo $m$ 
$$v := e^{-1} \equiv 2753 \pmod {3120}$$
And now evaluate $$c^v\equiv 2790^{2753}\equiv 65 \pmod {3233}$$

The main problem for larger values (as in RSA) is of course finding $\varphi(n)$ from $n$; and the $\gcd$ condition is one of the assumptions of school-book RSA.

Comment: Is there an algorithm to find modular e'th root in general?

Comment: If you know the prime factorization of $n$ you can use the Chinese Remainder theorem as usual, with the receipt from above. But note that even the modular square root problem  (i.e. $e=2$) is hard if  n is a composite integer whose prime factors are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You can brute-force it with relatively modest means:

```
a= 1; a17= 1 # a17 == a^17 mod 3233
while a17 != 2790:
    a+= 1
    a17= (a * a) % 3233;
    a17= (a17 * a17) % 3233;
    a17= (a17 * a17) % 3233;
    a17= (a17 * a17) % 3233;
    a17= (a * a17) % 3233
print a
```

Of course stops at $a=65$.

Comment: Thanks for your code. Doses this code apply to All n,c?

Comment: Well, you see where $n, c$ appear in the code, and you can substitute (but the exponentiation was hard-coded).